Reason for "must be pom but is jar" error
I am getting one error in pom file. This is the error when I am running pom file only. It is showing the error on the 6th line of the pom file, on
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5
[FATAL] The parents form a cycle: com.example:mynewfiledemo1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.5 @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:mynewfiledemo1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Bhagyashree Meena\Downloads\chatdemo\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.example:chatpage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5
[ERROR]     The parents form a cycle: com.example:mynewfiledemo1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.5 @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

This is my pom file code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mynewfiledemo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mynewfiledemo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Why am I getting this error?
I have also tried to make a new project, but it is also showing this error in the newly created project. I think I am making some mistake in Spring Initializr.

Your pom looks good but it should ends with  and contains spring-boot-maven-plugin

Your pom works for me. Try to delete .m2 folder inside home folder. .m2 contains downloaded packages, probably they are corrupted

The part about cyclic dependencies is interesting. Why are you specifying spring boot as a parent project, and not as a dependency?

@Rogue because it is spring boot parent and we are building spring boot project

The given pom does not produce this error message [FATAL] The parents form a cycle: com.example:mynewfiledemo1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> 

I see, it's a provider from spring for setup/env vars. Weird, but not the problem.
